# Prisma gives error: in connector bad handshake

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have a remote MySQL server which I can connect to via my command line.
But when I try to run `npx prisma db pull`
it gives me this error:

`Error: Error in connector: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: Server error: ERROR 08S01 (1043): Bad handshake'`

### What did I do

- My prisma database url is: `mysql://sven:<URL-ENCODEDPASSWORD>@<IP-ADDRESS>3306/portfolio?sslidentity=client-identity.p12&sslpassword=<SSL-PASSORD>&sslcert=ca.pem`
- I copied the ssl certificate and keys like this, I made sure I copied it right.
  :

  `sudo cat /var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem`

  `sudo cat /var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem`

  `sudo cat /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem`
- following the [documention](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql#configuring-an-ssl-connection) I made the one sslindentiy of it.

When connecting from my command line I do this with the following command: `mysql -usven -h<ip-address> -p`

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is your MySQL Version? Is it happening after upgrading to a recent version of MySQL? Also could you specify the Prisma version that you are using?

Comment: I just initialized the project, mysql version`8.0.30` and prisma version: `4.4.0`

Comment: Where is your database hosted? Is your repository open source, I can try to replicate this locally and see if I can find the root cause of this issue.

Comment: There is a similar issue open here https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/16886 
It doesn't look like it affects a lot of people and the current workaround is to pin the MySQL version to v8.0.29
I'm trying to get a reproduction, so we can fix this.